# Array Index out of Bound exception in a program for reverse of an array

Tags: java, arrays

```
Here is the code to reverse an array

import java.util.*;
class middle {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int a[]=new int[]{2,3,65,4,7,8,9};
        int c[]=new int[a.length-1];
        int k=0;
        for(int i=a.length;i>0;i++){
            c[k]=a[i];
            k++;
        }

        System.out.println("Reverse of an array");
        for(int i=0;i<c.length;i++)
            System.out.print(c[i]+"   ");
    }
}
```

while running gives Array index out of bound exception:7
where the code is going wrong?

Comment: `array[array.length]` will *always* be out of bounds. Array indices go from 0 to *length-1*. See also the [official tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

Comment: Please please **PLEASE** format your code. Also, please use Java naming conventions - classes should be in `PascalCase`; `Middle` not `middle`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you did mistake here , you need to mention the length of array `a.length` not `a.length-1` for c and the values in for loop conditions should have like  `for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)` `i` should be decremented. : modified code is here:

```
int a[]=new int[]{2,3,65,4,7,8,9};
int c[]=new int[a.length];

int k=0;
for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{

c[k]=a[i];
k++;

}
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful if you pointed out the mistakes and explained why your modifications solve the issues. :)

Answer (score 1):

`a.length` is out of bound for `a`

```
for(int i=a.length;i>0;i++)
{
 c[k]=a[i];
 k++;
}
```

then,

```
int c[]=new int[a.length-1];
```

you need same length array for, not `length - 1` for reverse array

Comment: @Raju your comment doesn't support -1

Answer (score 1):

To loop through the array backwards, you need to change **all three conditions** in your loop, like so:

```
for(int i=a.length-1;i>=0;i--)
{
 c[k]=a[i];
 k++;
}
```

**Let's take this apart:**

```
int i=a.length-1;
```

You must begin at `a.length-1`, as arrays use 0-based indexing and `a.length` is out of bounds.

```
i>=0;
```

You need to iterate until `i>=0`, as `i>0` will miss one element of your array.

```
i--
```

You need to decrement `i`, as the loop will always access out of bounds indexes/never terminate otherwise.

P.S. As @Jigar mentioned, you need to initialize `c` as `int c[]=new int[a.length];`.